# Migration from antd4 to antd5 less to css in js

Tags: reactjs, less, antd, css-in-js

In a complicated aplication that was built on antd4, that has many different less files 100+, upgrading to antd5 do I have to update all the files to be using cssinjs or can I keep the old less files and only the new features to be built using cssinjs?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to rewrite your code you'll need to use compatible package to covert it into v4 less variables and use less-loader to inject them.

Take a look into antd migration [docs](https://ant.design/docs/react/migration-v5#less-migration).

If you want to rewrite your code, here's an example of how I do in my projects:

```
// styles.ts

import { CSSProperties } from 'react'
import { theme as antdTheme } from 'antd'

type StylesType = {
  Container: CSSProperties
}

/**
 * Styles*
 *
 * @return {StylesType} styles
 */
function Styles(): StylesType {
  const { useToken } = antdTheme
  const { token: theme } = useToken()

  const Container: CSSProperties = {
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: theme.colorPrimary
  }

  return {
    Container
  }
}

export default Styles
```

Usage:

```
// component.tsx
import Styles from 'path/to/styles'

...

function MyComponent() {
  const S = Styles()

  ...

  return (
    <div styles={S.Container}>
      MyComponent
    </div>
  )
}
```